# Telnet Java code working in Windows but not in Unix

Tags: java, unix, pom.xml, telnet, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to **Telnet** to a **server** from the method `SwitchClient` and authenticate using a password. I have written 2 methods, `readUntil` to read and traverse till the output end, and `write` to write the password.

I am using **Spring Tool Suite** for my development and building a Jar file. Additionally I am using UTF-8 encoding in the `pom.xml`. This same piece of code is working fine in Windows machine while its failing in UNIX with "Password Timeout" at `write` method and printing junk values.

**One interesting fact**: I tried to create a jar with this standalone class file, and executed in Unix box. To my surprise it worked fine without any issues. Whereas the jar created from Spring Tool Suite **still does not work**. Please help.

```
public SwitchClient(String server, String user, String password) {
  try {         
    telnet.connect(server, 23);
    in = telnet.getInputStream();
    out = new PrintStream(telnet.getOutputStream(),false,"UTF-8");
    readUntil("Enter Password: ");
    write("password");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public String readUntil(String pattern) {
  try {
    char lastChar = pattern.charAt(pattern.length() - 1);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    char ch = (char) in.read();
    while (true) {
      System.out.print(ch);
      sb.append(ch);
      if (ch == lastChar) {
        if (sb.toString().endsWith(pattern)) {
          return sb.toString();
        }
      }
    ch = (char) in.read();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
}

public void write(String value) {
  try {
    out.println(value);
    out.flush();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hint: you want us to spend our time to help you. So you please the 2 minutes it takes to **properly** format/indent your source code; instead of dropping such a **mess** on us.

Comment: Regarding your actual problem: when you open a telnet session from the command line on your Unix system - does that work? If not, forget about doing it from Java. You see, there might be some firewall somewhere preventing you to get to that remote server.

Comment: I've reduced the over-formatting, and tip: use `backticks` to format code, such as methods. Respecting case conventions seriously helps readability too.

Comment: Sorry, I was new to here and hence missed to format. Edited now. @GhostCat, I am able to manually enter the password in unix. On top of that this code works perfectly in from my windows machine.

Comment: Great ... that is one good thing then!

Comment: The same type of error **Password Timeout.** occurs if I leave the prompt idle for some time after writing the password and without hitting an _Enter_. Is that the \n need to be added as to mimic the _Enter_ ?

Comment: @Prasant Good news, `out.println(value);` already sends a `\n`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, You are rite but to my surprise its still not working in Unix :-(. Not able to find out what is the problem here.

Comment: @All, **One interesting fact**: I tried to create a jar with this standalone class file, and executed in Unix box. To my surprise it worked fine without any issues. Now is it something related to a build issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix this issue by just adding write("\r\n"); after the write("password");

Thanks all for your efforts. :-)

[Please refer this URL](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/105671-spring-integration-simple-tcp-client)